# What is the long game for Blazor Server and Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I'm well aware of the pros and cons of Blazor Server vs Blazor WebAssembly.  That said, which one should we use to build, say, a new company website?  While "it depends" might be your answer, it's more than which one checks more boxes in our criteria.

Does anyone know what is Microsoft's long-term roadmap/direction?  If we were to build it in Blazor Server and then learn two years from now that Microsoft wants to deprecate it in favor of WebAssembly, then we will have made a big mistake (like when we chose LINQ over EF but don't get me started on that one!).  If we thought WebAssembly was more future-proof (especially given all the buzz), but both end up being fully touted/supported long-term, then it may have made more sense to have used Blazor Server (depending on criteria).

That said, criteria can change (oh the humanity!).  If we build it in Blazor Server but our CEO then says he wants it to render a calculator even if offline (ok, that's not going to happen but you know what I mean), then we're unable to do that.  Conversely, if we build it WebAssembly and then the business wants something that (I don't know.. for it to show for SEO statistics), it would have been better to have gone the other way with Blazor Server.

In today's world, most companies have a website and a native mobile app (Dominoes, MGM Grand, whatever).  I realize WebAssembly with PWA is a way we smaller companies can have a pseudo-native app without actually having to write one (Xamarin to iOS, Android), but what's the long game here?  You see where I'm going with this question?  It's not about the specific pros and cons of each, it's about trying to survey the landscape five years from now and make the right decision today for that future.  My gut tells me WebAssembly for everything but my gut also told me LINQ over EF.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: I've voted to close this as it's an opinion question, but I'll add a bit of guidance. Blazor server-side and client-side WASM Blazor are pretty much the same animal. The component model and rendering system is common to both, the main difference is that one runs on the server, the other on the client. It's possible to write a Blazor application which will run on both without modification - the key is to abstract out the data access so it will be portable. So for example, don't code directly to EF models in a server-side app, code to a data service abstraction.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this announcement to ONE net, the direction MS is taking: 
[The Journey to One .NET](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2020/BOD106)

Globally speaking we are heading toward cross platform uniformity based on Net.Core, Blazor and Xamarin:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-multi-platform-app-ui/

Comment: And just recently, also WPF Applications.